# Decode escaped strings by sqlite3 in python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

When you add a string to a sqlite3 database in the right way in python it of course escapes the string. But when I retrieve it I want to decode it to print it. How can I do that in python 3?

Comment: SQLite does not modify strings. Show your code.

Comment: Oh! My bad, I had inserted a &amp; and thought it was like that in the db because sqlite was escaping it, but it was me the one that inserted it escaped in the first place. Sorry